# Receiving mail with in Spring integration with Java config

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, dsl

I want to receive mails with Spring Integration. I've found a lot of examples with xml config, but I haven't found any with Java DSL config. How can I write the following xml config with Java DSL?

```
<int-mail:inbound-channel-adapter id="imapAdapter"
      store-uri="imaps://[username]:[password]@imap.gmail.com/INBOX"
      channel="receiveChannel"
      should-delete-messages="true">
      <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="1" fixed-rate="5000"/>
</int-mail:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

I've tried the following solution, but I have no idea, how to add poller to it.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mailListener() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Mail.imapInboundAdapter("imaps://[username]:[password]@imap.gmail.com/INBOX").shouldDeleteMessages(true).get())
            .<Message>handle((payload, header) -> logMail(payload))
            .get();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the [DSL reference](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference).

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mailListener() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Mail.imapInboundAdapter("imaps://[username]:[password]@imap.gmail.com/INBOX")
             .shouldDeleteMessages(true).get(), 
             e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(5000).maxMessagesPerPoll(1)))
        .<Message>handle((payload, header) -> logMail(payload))
        .get();
}
```

Comment: I am getting the following error while trying to create pop3 connection using the above code o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler : org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: failure occurred while polling for mail; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: authorization failed My credentials are correct I double checked that.

Comment: Don't comment on old answers; ask a new question showing your configuration. Clearly your credentials are wrong; most likely your password has some special character(s) that need escaping.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50989745/spring-boot-integration-mail-authorization-failed-error please have a look into this @gary

Comment: @GaryRussell could you please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57126841/how-to-enable-folder-read-write-mode-in-spring-integration-config)