# Spring boot integration mail - authorization failed error

Tags: spring-integration, jakarta-mail, spring-dsl

Following is my spring configuration bean for pop3 connection,

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow mailListener() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Mail.pop3InboundAdapter("pop3://sample.test:Sample2test_1@xxx.xx.x.xx/INBOX")
                 .shouldDeleteMessages(true).get(), 
                 e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(5000).maxMessagesPerPoll(1)))
            .<Message>handle((payload, header) -> logMail(payload))
            .get();
    }
```

Also double checked the credentials that looks good.
Getting the below exception,

> 2018-06-22 19:27:54.351 ERROR 2092 --- [ask-scheduler-2]
>   o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   :
>   org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: failure occurred
>   while polling for mail; nested exception is
>   javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: authorization failed    at
>   org.springframework.integration.mail.MailReceivingMessageSource.receive(MailReceivingMessageSource.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:224)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:245)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:58)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:190)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:186)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:353)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:344)
>     at
>   org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
>     at
>   org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
>     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: authorization failed    at
>   com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:208)   at
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)  at
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)  at
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)  at
>   org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.connectStoreIfNecessary(AbstractMailReceiver.java:286)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.openFolder(AbstractMailReceiver.java:293)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.receive(AbstractMailReceiver.java:319)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.mail.MailReceivingMessageSource.receive(MailReceivingMessageSource.java:112)
>     ... 19 more

Answer (score 0):

There is an option like this:

```
/**
 * The Java Mail properties.
 * @param javaMailProperties the javaMailProperties.
 * @return the spec.
 * @see AbstractMailReceiver#setJavaMailProperties(Properties)
 */
public S javaMailProperties(Properties javaMailProperties) {
```

You can specify there `mail.debug = true` to trace what's going on with mail protocol during interaction.

**UPDATE**

We have this in your logs:

```
DEBUG POP3: connecting to host "172.16.1.45", port 995, isSSL false
19:54:46.746 [task-scheduler-1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'errorChannel'
19:54:46.753 [task-scheduler-1] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel - preSend on channel 'errorChannel', message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: failure occurred while polling for mail; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Connect failed;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect, headers={id=290f4c5a-2dfe-d7cb-0637-a0e9f0394daa, timestamp=1529677486753}]
```

So, it can't just connect to the `172.16.1.45:995`. There is no authentication handshake yet.

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Can I replace **pop.gmail.com** instead of **172.16.1.45:995**
I can't get a clue for this, Does it happen due to any proxy or firewall

Comment: Right, you can do that. According your logs the URL must be like `pop3://sharanraj.siluvaipillai:*****@pop.gmail.com/INBOX`. However for GMail you should consider to you `application token` instead of your original password: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth

Comment: If you can't even connect you're probably running into a [proxy or firewall issue](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#condebug).  The JavaMail FAQ describes how to [connect through a proxy server](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#proxy).